# regex a number range

Tags: regex

i ´ve got the following problem:

how can i regex a string like this:

```
?partner=87835223&token=yygQWaaT
```

for 87835223 and yygQWaaT can be any other combination

thanks for help!

Comment: please be clear with the question and do specify the language you are using

Comment: @rock321987 i have steam trade link like this: https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=87835223&token=yygQWaaT and i would like to check the syntax of this with a php script

Comment: so you want to capture the value of `partner` and `token`?

Comment: @rock321987 i will check that the url, that the user add to my website, is not a url like google.de. it must be this steam link

Comment: i am not getting you..are you trying to match `?partner=something&token=something` ?

Comment: @rock321987 yeah thats what i trying to match. sorry for my bad mode of expression

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this regex will suffice

```
\?partner=\d+&token=\w+
           ^^       ^^
           ||   Matches one or more alphanumeric characters
     Matches one or
      more digits
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sM5dI1/1)**

*PHP Code*

```
$re = "/\\?partner=\\d+&token=\\w+/"; 
$str = "?partner=87835223&token=yygQWaaT"; 
print(preg_match($re, $str, $matches));
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/30FNw8)**

Comment: Thank you! This will help me!

Comment: @iSeven glad to help

Comment: @rock321987 your solution will not work in a generalized string, it will work for this example only

Comment: @VikashKesarwani please give an example

Comment: @rock321987 this string for example `?partner=87835223&token=yygQWaaT&new_key=put_some_value_here"`

Comment: @VikashKesarwani on what basis are you saying that there will be `&new_key...` in the input?

Comment: @VikashKesarwani anyhow, i have made an assumption that the part mentioned will be in end of string because the site URL structure is like that..remove `$` if you want to match it anywhere in string

Comment: @rock321987 My point was that user asked to parse a string like this. This string may or may not be part of actual problem.

Comment: @rock321987 leave it then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regular expression `=\w+`, but this way you will get `=` also in the match, so you will have to take care of that

```
Input = ?partner=87835223&token=yygQWaaT
Matches = =87835223, =yygQWaaT
```